# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: node.js, angular

I would like to update my shopping-cart whenever an item is added but instead I keep getting this error on the browser which I believe is the reason why my shopping-cart isn't updating.

shopping-cart.services.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShoppingCartService {

  shopping_cart_items:any[]=[];

  constructor() { }
  addProduct = (product) =>{ //
   let items = this.get_shopping_cart_items();

   if(items){
     items.push(product);
     localStorage.setItem('shopping_cart', JSON.stringify(items));
   }else
   {
     this.shopping_cart_items.push(product);

     localStorage.setItem('shopping_cart', JSON.stringify(this.get_shopping_cart_items));
         
   }
 
     
  }

  get_shopping_cart_items =()=>{
    let items = localStorage.getItem('shopping_cart');
   return JSON.parse(items);
  }

  getCartLength =()=>{
    let items = this.get_shopping_cart_items();
    return items? this.get_shopping_cart_items().length:0
        
  }


      
}
```

HTML FILE:

```html
 <div class = "header_menu_cart">
      <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
    <p class = "header_cart_number">{{shoppingCart.getCartLength()}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, In your else statement you are not calling the method, just passing the function name as a value:

```
this.shopping_cart_items.push(product);

     localStorage.setItem('shopping_cart', JSON.stringify(this.get_shopping_cart_items())) <--- changed this to method call
```

And, that is why it is giving you an error while converting string to a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(var) is a function which is only able to parse JSON data. If your data is not in JSON format then it will give you an error.

So, first of all, check your var is in json format or not using below method:

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

 get_shopping_cart_items =()=>{
    let items = localStorage.getItem('shopping_cart');
    if(IsJsonString(items)) return JSON.parse(items);
    else return {};
  }
```